# How to get value of these in javascript on click of any of the button

Tags: javascript

how to get value of these in javascript using `document.getElementById`

```
<input type="radio" name="rbRate" id="1" value="1"/>1 
<input type="radio" name="rbRate" id="2" value="2"/>2 
<input type="radio" name="rbRate" id="3" value="3"/>3 
<input type="radio" name="rbRate" id="4" value="4"/>4 
<input type="radio" name="rbRate" id="5" value="5"/>5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to them via `document.getElementById`, and then get their value from their `value` property. But note that that will give you the `value` assigned to the radio button, whether the button is selected or not. (For that, you look at its `checked` property.)

So for instance:

```
var n, checkedValue, rdo;

for (n = 1; n <= 5; ++n) {
    rdo = document.getElementById(n); // n will get promoted to a string automatically
    if (rdo.checked) {
        checkedValue = rdo.value;
        break;
    }
}
```

The `checkedValue` variable will be the value of the checked button, or `undefined` if none of them is checked.

Side note: Although `id` values starting with digits are okay as of HTML5, they used to be invalid (HTML4 and earlier) and are still invalid in CSS. It's best to stay away from them.

Answer (score 0):

use the `value` property, like this `document.getElementById('1').value`